# PHP: Replace "+" symbols with "Space"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using an echo tag to output a few font properties chosen by a user on my site, through *Wordpress* > *Appreances* > *Theme Options*.

Once they have selected the font that they like from one of the select menus on this page, it gets called into the source code for the front-end to display like so:

**header.php**

```
<style>
<?php $typography = of_get_option('main-text');
if ($typography) {          
echo 'p {
    font: ' . $typography['size']. ' '.$typography['face'] . '; 
    font-style: ' . $typography['style'] . '; 
    color: '.$typography['color'].';    
}';

$typography = str_replace(' ','+',$typography); 
} 
?>
</style>
```

As the choices they have in the select menu include *Google Web Fonts*, some of the font faces contain `+` symbols which I would like to replace with a simple  `space`  instead.

As I'm a little unfamiliar with PHP, I was wondering how would I correctly write out something like

```
$typography = str_replace(' ','+',$typography);
```

for the above script, as what I've tried/where I've placed this, isn't working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first 2 parameters of the str_replace function are backwards. Also if you want it to replace *before* echoing out, then you would have to do the replace, well, before echoing it out.

If you only need the replace done for the 'face' key, then you could do:

```
<style>
<?php $typography = of_get_option('main-text');
if ($typography)
{    
    $typography['face'] = str_replace('+', ' ', $typography['face']); 

    echo 'p {
        font: ' . $typography['size']. ' '.$typography['face'] . '; 
        font-style: ' . $typography['style'] . '; 
        color: '.$typography['color'].';    
    }';
} 
?>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  $typography = str_replace(' ','+',$typography);
```

should be

```
 $typography = str_replace('+',' ',$typography);
```

in order to replace a `+` with a `space`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Hanky.